# Effect of Generics on the execution time

Tags: java, performance, collections, arraylist, hashmap

I have a class which gets data from data base and sends to UI to generate charts.

The execution time of the class is 14 seconds

```
    List listOfCLI =new ArrayList();
List listOfRRV =new ArrayList();
List listOfROP =new ArrayList();
List listOfACR =new ArrayList();
List listOfPIN =new ArrayList();
List listOfRIS =new ArrayList();
List listOfTAA =new ArrayList();
List listOfTAR =new ArrayList();
List listOfPHA =new ArrayList();
List listOfSAR =new ArrayList();
List listOfGRQ =new ArrayList();
List listOfADC =new ArrayList();
```

When i change the code to

```
 List<DataMS> listOfCLI =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfRRV =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfROP =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfACR =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfPIN =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfRIS =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfTAA =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfTAR =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfPHA =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfSAR =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfGRQ =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
List<DataMS> listOfADC =new ArrayList<DataMS>();
```

the execution time goes up to 17 seconds..
Why did addition of the Generic suggested by eclipse has such  an adverse impact.

Also can you suggest the optimal way of using Generics to reduce the execution time

```
**Map<String, List> reqCLI =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqRRV =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqROP =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqACR =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqPIN =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqTAA =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqTAR =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqRIS =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqPHA =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqSAR =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqGRQ =new HashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, List> reqADC =new HashMap<String, List>();

        List<Map<String, List>> listCLI=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listRRV=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listROP=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listACR=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listPIN=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listTAA=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listTAR=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listRIS=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listPHA=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listSAR=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listGRQ=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();
        List<Map<String, List>> listADC=new ArrayList<Map<String, List>>();**
```

these are the remaining collection's used

Comment: List or List<DataMS> will be the same thing (List<DataMS> -> List)

Comment: Generics has no effect in execution time. Do you have benchmark results to prove your point?

Comment: Like i said execution time went up to 27 seconds after adding List<DataMS> listOfCLI =new ArrayList<DataMS>();in place of  List listOfCLI =new ArrayList(); iam running it right now... As we speak

Comment: what JVM do you use to execute the code ?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. The generic types won't make it to the JVM. Can you create a small benchmark which proves it?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: LinkedHashSetTest linkedTest = new LinkedHashSetTest();            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println("Trend SysOut "+linkedTest.getReqTrendData("08/10/2013", "12/10/2013"));
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
   System.out.println("startTime"+startTime+"Time difference: " + duration);
   logger.debug("==Total Time of Exceution====" + duration/1000000000);

Comment: How much over head does a Data Base hit create? From JAVA to Oracle.

Comment: This is not a good benchmark since it contains too many souts inside which falsify what you really want to measure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java explains pitfalls in Java benchmarking well.

Answer (score 2):

Because of **type erasure** (see http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101), generic types are not represented in the compiled bytecode, so there should be no difference in performance at execution time.  The parameterized types are checked solely at compile time.

Comment: How much over head does a Data Base hit create? From JAVA to Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that the java compiler can insert **implicit casts**:

```
List a = new ArrayList();
b.add("foo");
List b = new ArrayList();
for (Object o : a) {
  b.add(o);  // Adding an object.
}
```

has no casts, but there are implicit casts in

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
b.add("foo");
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
// Each element is implicitly cast to a String which requires
// a runtime type check.
for (String s : a) {
  b.add(s);
}
```

That's the only difference at the byte-code level.

It's hard to tell whether that would account for the discrepancy you're seeing without knowing the number of writes and reads that you're doing but RTTI checks are pretty cheap.

---

Preferring batch operations like `List.addAll` and `Map.putAll` instead of looping should eliminate that overhead if that is the culprit.